# Did I compute this integral over a submanifold correclty?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, submanifold

I want to compute the integral $$\int_{M} yz\,\,\, dS$$ where $M=\{(x,y,z):x,y,z\geq 0, x+y+z-1=0\}$.

I tried it as follows:

Let us consider the chart $$\phi:[0,1]^2\rightarrow M,\,\, \phi(x,y)=(x,y,1-x-y)$$ Now I computed $$D\phi=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}1&0\\0&1\\-1&-1\end{array}\right)$$ Then the gram matris is $$G_\phi=\left(\begin{array}{rrr} 2&1\\1&2\end{array}\right)$$ which impies that the gram determinant $g_\phi=3$.

Then I computed
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 y(1-x-y)\sqrt 3  dxdy& =\sqrt{3}\int_0^1 (xy-\frac{1}{2}x^2y-xy^2|_{x=0}^1)dy\\
&=\sqrt{3}\int_0^1\frac{1}{2}y-y^2 dy\\
&=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{12}.
\end{align}

But I think this is wrong since we have a negative value or did I do it correct?

Could someone take a look at it?

Comment: Your chart $[0,1]^2$ is too big and contains negative $z$-values.

Comment: But when I draw the set, then it is the triangle with the verces $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ and why $x,y$ are not in the intervall $[0,1]$?

Comment: They are in $[0,1]$ but it contains more. e.g.  $(x, y)=(1,1)$ should not be there since that would give $z=-1$

Comment: would it work with $[0,1]\times [0,-x]$

Comment: Something like that. But it is not really a rectangle, you need a triangle

Comment: sorry I wanted to write $[0,1]\times [0,1-x]$ this was a tipo. does it work now?

Comment: I suppose what you meant is $\{ (x, y) : \in [0,1], y\in [0,1-x]\}$. That would be correct.

Comment: Oh yes. Okey thank you. but another short question, my $\phi$ defined on your set from above is a chart right? should then your set not be open by definition, otherwise it isn't a chart?

Comment: Depending on your background I guess. The boundary is really negligible that it does not matter if you use the closed one or just the interior (the same holds also for one variable calculus : it does not matter if you integrate on $(a, b)$ or $[a, b]$)

Comment: ah okey perfect thanks!!